# How to clear a textbox when a user starts to type new data

Tags: c#

I'm creating an income tax calculator. I created a new event that clears the data in the income textbox when the user types new data. It is not clearing the data when you type, it just continues the number.

```
        // txtIncome
        // 
        this.txtIncome.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(125, 41);
        this.txtIncome.Name = "txtIncome";
        this.txtIncome.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(106, 20);
        this.txtIncome.TabIndex = 4;
        this.txtIncome.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(clearIncome);
```

The above coding is what I gathered from the textbook to add for the event to work.

```
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        income = Convert.ToDecimal(txtIncome.Text);
        incomeCalcualtor();
        txtOwed.Text = Convert.ToString(owed);
        txtIncome.Focus();

    }

    private void incomeCalcualtor()
    {
        if (income <= 9225)

            owed = (int)income * .10m;

        else if ((int)income > 9225m && (int)income <= 37450)
            owed = 922.50m + (int)((income - 9225) * .15m);

        else if (income > 37450 && income <= 90750)
            owed = 5156.25m + (int)((income - 37450) * .25m);

        else if (income > 90750 && income <= 189300)
            owed = 18481.25m + (int)((income - 90750) * .28m);

        else if (income >= 189300 && income <= 411500)
            owed = 46075.25m + (int)((income - 189300) * .33m);

        else if (income >= 411500 && income <= 413200)
            owed = 119401.25m + (int)((income - 411500) * .35m);

        else if (income <= 413200)
            owed = 11996.25m + (int)((income - 413200) * 39.6m);
    }


    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void clearIncome(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtIncome.Text = "";
    }
```

A textbox that clears when there is new data being entered

Comment: I don't see a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement click event and use clear method like this

```
 this.txtIncome.Click += new System.EventHandler(clearIncome);

private void clearIncome(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtIncome.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you! This was not explained in my textbook!

Answer (score 1):

This might help. The below code will clear the textbox `txtIncome` when it is `double clicked`.

Inculde `MouseDoubleClick` event and `Name` in `txtIncome` as below.

```
<TextBox MouseDoubleClick="txtIncome_MouseDoubleClick" Name="txtIncome" />

private void txtIncome_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  txtIncome.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you out. However, you can use the onclick event, and SelectAll(). This will have a similar affect, and is very common in windows apps

```
private void TextBoxOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.SelectAll();
    textBox.Focus(); // might not need this
}
```